# Power BI using 90+% CPU while doing.. what?

Tags: performance, powerbi

I have a 9Mb PBIX containing small tables and one table with 250k rows. Data imported from various xlsx & JSON sources. Machine is Windows 10 Pro, 2.6GHz, 64 bit, 16GB RAM.

On the Power BI service online the performance is ok, but on desktop it's practically unworkable. With task manager I can see that it is using 7Mb of memory, but almost 100% CPU, half an hour after opening - while on a blank tab with no visualisations.

I don't understand what it is doing in the background and how I can improve the situation.

There is the 'Allow data preview to download in the background' setting, but I think this is only relevant to the query editor? Would clearing the cache or changing cache settings help?

I am aware of performance analyzer and the query diagnostics tools, but neither seem relevant since the queries are not refreshing and there are no visualisations loading.

Am at a bit of a loss - any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: In Task Manager in the Details tab which processes are using the most CPU? That will help determine if it’s Query Editor or something else.

Comment: Thanks Greg,
It's mostly the mashup evaluation containers, which I believe is the query editor? Is the data model not saved with the pbix? i.e should it not have to reprocess all the queries every time you open the pbix?

Comment: Actually, turning off "Allow data preview to download in the background" did a trick for me. Additionally, you can try to create a blank page in your PowerBI and see if CPU spikes on a blank page.
I also found this article helpful -> [PowerBI performance issues](https://www.designmind.com/business-intelligence/power-bi-performance-issues/)

Comment: Thanks Justyna - I had read that article. The trouble is it glosses over the issue I'm having when it says 'Wait for the report CPU % to approach zero' ... since the problem I am having is that that in itself is taking forever. I don't understand, because if during that time Power BI doesn't have the full data model loaded to memory, how is it rendering visualisations correctly? (To clarify, the report works but very slowly for the first half hour after opening. Once that time has passed and it's not running at 90-100% CPU, everything is fine).

Answer (score 2):

Update: Having disabled parallel load and background refresh in Data load settings I noticed that finally the issue seemed to go away (though not immediately). Eventually, when reopening the pbix, mashup containers did not appear and CPU and memory was not being killed. Then at some point Power BI got stuck and had to close and the problem reappeared even though the data load settings were still disabled. Restarting the machine seemed to clear the problem once again.

It seems then, that some zombie processes can persist through application close and re-open. Has anyone else noticed this, can confirm or refute it, suggest what is going on or any steps on how to avoid/prevent? It's very annoying!
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have also noticed the same issue, for opening 5 mb pbix file, power bi eating 12 GB of memory, and 90%+ CPU utilization, Power BI Desktop is poorly managed product by Microsoft.

Comment: This is not an answer, please leave such posts for the comment section